# dplyr mutate with an ifelse using dynamic variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyeval

I want to use as string as a variable name such as this:

```
var <- 'vs'
var_max <-max(mtcars[, 8], na.rm = T)

#change the max value of the 'vs' column
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(get(var) = ifelse(get(var) == var_max, 100, get(var)))
```

but this returns:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(get(var) ="
```

Another way to do this without a string is:

```
var_max = max(mtcars$vs)
my_mtcars = mtcars %>% mutate(vs = ifelse(vs == var_max, 100, vs))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `tidy evaluation`: convert `var` from string to variable using `sym` then unquote it inside `mutate` using `!!`. Note the use of `:=` on the left hand side of `ifelse` too.

```r
library(dplyr)

var <- 'vs'
var_max <- max(mtcars[, 8], na.rm = T)
var_max
#> [1] 1

#change the max value of the 'vs' column
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(!!sym(var) := ifelse(!!sym(var) == var_max, 100, !!sym(var)))
my_mtcars
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec  vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46   0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02   0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61 100  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44 100  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02   0  0    3    2
#> Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22 100  0    3    1
#> Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84   0  0    3    4
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00 100  0    4    2
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90 100  0    4    2
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30 100  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90 100  0    4    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40   0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60   0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00   0  0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98   0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82   0  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42   0  0    3    4
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47 100  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52 100  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90 100  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01 100  0    3    1
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87   0  0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30   0  0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41   0  0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05   0  0    3    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90 100  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70   0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90 100  1    5    2
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50   0  1    5    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50   0  1    5    6
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60   0  1    5    8
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60 100  1    4    2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>